# How to load the CSS first in node.js and express?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, asynchronous

I am working in node.js and using ejs for my front end programming. While loading the page, it displays all the content in an unmanaged way but after loading the CSS its show correct layout.

Is there a way to load the CSS first so that the page shows / loads correctly? I heard that there is a way related to async, although I don't know how to use the function properly.

Comment: can be in jquery? the answer?

Comment: yeh please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Put

`<link href="/public/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">`

in begining of *HEAD*, and *CSS* will load before page will render

Answer (score 0):

1 - hide all the page

```
<body style="display: none;">
```

2 -With jQuery show all, when all files are loaded:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
  $("body").show();
});
</script>
```

or jQuery instead $:

```
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  $("body").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: its working but its take too much time is there a way to show the loader in this because blank screen look weird

Comment: maybe create a loading ? what do you think?

Comment: i am thing i want loader can we add?